# Excel VBA Check Value of Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to slightly modify this code to look at every cell in columns O, X, AG, AP, and AY to find if any cell is above 60 and display the `Warning` message box.

What am I missing here? Can anyone help?

```
Private Sub workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("O:O") > 60 Then

Response = MsgBox("WARNING!", vbOKCancel + vbExclamation)

End If

If Response = 2 Then

Cancel = True

Else

End If

End Sub
```

I can't find the right code to express the range needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through each worksheet and perform the column validation sequentially.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim colRng As Range
    Dim rRng As Range, oSht As Worksheet
    For Each oSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set colRng = oSht.Range("O:O,X:X,AG:AG,AP:AP,AY:AY")
        For Each rRng In colRng.Areas
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rRng, ">60") > 0 Then
                If MsgBox("WARNING!", vbOKCancel + vbExclamation) = 2 Then Cancel = True
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilize `Application.WorkSheetFunction` methods and use `COUNTIFS()` to detect numbers greater than `60`.

```
Private Sub workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim Response As Variant

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("O:O"), ">60") > 0 Then
        Response = MsgBox("WARNING!", vbOKCancel + vbExclamation)
            If Response = vbCancel Then
                Cancel = ture
            End If
    End If
    
End Sub
```